# How do I find a character followed by a character in a char array Java?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I am trying to find a character array inside of a character array so that in the array, A would be followed by B. For some reason, I do not get an error but I also cannot get it to do the work I want when I have an array with the combination. I was just wondering if someone could explain what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction.

```
char[] Array = new char[] {'A','B','C','D'....};
char A = 'A';
char B = 'B';
....
for (int i = 0 ; i < Array.length; i ++) {
  if (Array[i] == A && Array[i++] == B) {
    //Work Here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, ont to make `i + 1` exceed array indexes, use `i < arr.length - 1` in for loop. Then, change `arr[i++]` to `arr[i+1]` in `if` statement.

```
char[] arr = new char[] {'A','B','C','D'....};
char a = 'A';
char b = 'B';
....
for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] == a && arr[i+1] == b) {
        //Work Here
    }
}
```

P.S: prop names are switched from capital case on purpose, to be consistent with the Java naming conventions.

Comment: And it complies to Java's naming conventions (`arr` could have been called `array` though).

Answer (score 0):

While I like aproaches in other answers so far better. If you want to stick to your approach,  you need the correct increment operator ( and also take care that the index doesn't exceed bounds):

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < Array.length-1;) {
  if (Array[i++] == A && Array[i] == B) {
    //Work Here
  }
}
```

For the one guy that doesn't believe it works, a run with some data:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    char[] Array = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B','C', 'D', 'B','A', 'A'};
    char A = 'A';
    char B = 'B';
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.length - 1;) {
        if (Array[i++] == A && Array[i] == B) {
            System.err.println("found at index;" +i);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
found at index;1
found at index;5
```

qed

Comment: working but you have to explain why his code is not working

Comment: Well I can give you a link that might help you understand it better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033035/java-logical-operator-short-circuit-mechanism

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in here:  `Array[i++] == B`, that is `i++` is a post increment which means it is first evaluated to `i` then it is incremented by `1`.

if `i=0` for example, `Array[i++] == B` gives you `Array[0] == B`, then after that `i=1`

to solve the issue: use `Array[i+1] == B` or `Array[++i] == B` instead

[read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371118/how-do-the-post-increment-i-and-pre-increment-i-operators-work-in-java)

So,
`i++` returns `i` but it increments `i` by `1`